# ios - unexpected behavior when trying to do NSLog from didViewAppear

Tags: ios, nslog

I have this setup in my class:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"get_business_ideas" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:rq];
}
```

The NSLog statement never appears in my logging screen, but the rest of the code seems to work because the uiWebView does render.  How could this be? It is a new project, so maybe I had to set something to make sure the logging could be seen?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the whole file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //load iphone image
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"building"]];
        imgView.frame = self.view.bounds; // to set the frame to your view's size
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
    }
    else
    {
        //load ipad image
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"building@2x"]];
        imgView.frame = self.view.bounds; // to set the frame to your view's size
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
    }

    NSLog(@"2");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in that method to see if it gets hit? Just click on the thin bar just to the left of the code on the line where you want the code to pause, if it never pauses there, that method is never called.

Comment: Where exactly are putting this?

Comment: @Kris Gellci just tried it. The code does get there, but the log never happens. Maybe I have the log screen not functioning correctly somehow?

Comment: I added the whole file in my original question. The code right above it does work by the way.

Comment: Definitely follow @KrisGellci's advice and put a breakpoint there.  See if it's ever called (and how far you get).

Comment: Do you know where to look for the log?  It goes into the console by default.  In older versions of Xcode you need to open that manually as a separate window.  In newer versions it opens automatically as a pane below the source display in your main window.

Comment: This is outside the constraints of your question... but why are you naming an iPad image @2x? That naming convention should be reserved for "standard" vs. "retina" images (not iPhone vs. iPad).

Comment: Yeah I am looking on that bottom section, but there is no log :(

Comment: I just, in xcode 4.5, did file - new project - ios - application - single view application. I pasted the whole of the code above into my ViewController. I ran it. Then I put some image files there and moved them to the front of the view and saw they displayed. Then I put some more logs in and ran that too. All that on the iPad simulator. Then I ran the whole thing on an iPad 2. And in every single case, the log output was exactly as one would expect. The "2" did appear. Every time. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Does adding the super call fix this for you?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"get_business_ideas" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:rq];
}
```

(no matter what ends up fixing your problem here... make sure you keep the [super] call in this method... it's required per the API documentation).

You mentioned that you have the bottom pane showing, but no debug messages are displaying.  Double check that the console section is being displayed in addition to the variables, by clicking the middle display icon, on the bottom panel (NOT the similar looking buttons on the top-right of Xcode):

[image: Console]

Comment: @J Shapiro just tried it and it didn't work :( I have another project where I just use NSLog without thinking about it and it just works. Not sure what is wrong in this case.

Comment: Why would that affect the OPs log?

Comment: You need to call `super` in this method, no matter what (per the documentation). What effects leaving that out would have, I'm not sure (since we don't have access to the ancestor chain of implementation files)... nevertheless, it's reasonable to assume that if the instructions in the API aren't followed, unexpected results may occur. 

The next step I'd make is to add a breakpoint to see if this method is even being called. There may be a problem in one of the earlier lifecycle methods.